# How to send images from one user to server and then display it back to all clients in the chat room using node js and socket.io?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, image, socket.io

I am working on chat application and i want users to select images of their choice from their system and once they select, it should be emitted and sent to server and again server should broadcast images to be able to visible to everyone.I want to do it using socket.io with node js. I have part of data reading using readAsDataURL but the thing is when i emit it to server, it doesn't work fine. It doesn't display images to other users.So what i am doing here is :

### client.js

```
socket.emit('image', data);
socket.io('image', function(data){
var a = "<img src="+data+" />";
$("body").append(a);
});
```

### server.js

```
socket.on('image', function(data)){
socket.emit('image', data);
});
```

**But it is not showing me the correct output. Please help :)**

**EDIT:**
***Here is the actual code:***

### Client.js

```
  <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var socket = io();
    $(".sendbtn").click(function () {
      sendText();
    });
    socket.on('message', function (msg) {
      var text2 = msg.replace('poc', 'toc');
      var app2 = $(".sap").append(text2);
    });

  var imag,zero;
    const image = $("#imag");
    console.log(image);
    $(image).change(function () {
      const file = this.files[0];
      var type = file['type'];
      if(type.split('/')[0]==='image'){
      console.log(file.name);
      if(file){
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.addEventListener("load",function () {
            zero=reader.result;
            console.log(zero);
          imag = "<img id='attachment' src="+this.result+" ></image>";
            var app3 = $(".sap").append(imag);
          });
          reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }
      socket.emit('image',zero);
    }
    else{
      console.log("This is not an image file");
      var type2 = type.split('/')[1];
      console.log("This is a "+type2+" file");
    }
    });

socket.on('image', function (data) {
  var imag2 = "<img id='attachment' src="+data+" />";
  var app3 = $(".sap").append(imag2);
  console.log("This is data <br>"+data);
});

function sendText(){
  var value = $(".reply").val();
  var text = "<p class='gon'>"+value+"</p>";
  var app = $(".sap").append(text);
  socket.emit('message', text);
}
  </script>
```

### Server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.static('public'));
const http = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.on('message',function (msg) {
    console.log(msg);
    socket.broadcast.emit('message', msg);
  });
  socket.on('image', function (imag) {
    console.log(imag);
    console.log("hello im here");
    socket.broadcast.emit('image', imag);
  });
  });
app.use(express.static('public'));
app.get('/req', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname+'/chat_app.html');
});
http.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Server is up and running on port 3000');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The socket.io getting started documentation is a great place to start https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Edit - If you show more of your project it would be easier to help diagnose what's going wrong. Right now there isnt enough information to sufficiently help.

Edit 2 - Answer below extends socket.io's starter chat example at https://github.com/socketio/chat-example to add support for sending images, very basic and large images take too long so a check for image size would be needed as well.

Client:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Socket.IO chat</title>
    <style>
      * { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }
      body { font: 13px Helvetica, Arial; }
      form { background: #000; padding: 3px; position: fixed; bottom: 0; width: 100%; }
      form input { border: 0; padding: 10px; width: 90%; margin-right: .5%; }
      form button { width: 9%; background: rgb(130, 224, 255); border: none; padding: 10px; }
      #messages { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
      #messages li { padding: 5px 10px; }
      #messages li:nth-child(odd) { background: #eee; }
      #messages { margin-bottom: 40px; }
      .disabled{ display: none; }
      img { height: 100px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form action="">
      <input type="text" class="disabled"/>
      <input type="file" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png"/> 
      
      <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function () {
        var socket = io();

        $('form').submit(function(){
          if($('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]){
            uploadFile();
          } else {
            socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
            $('#m').val('');
          }
          return false;
        });
        
        socket.on("image", function(info) {
          if (info.buffer) {
            $('#messages').append($('<li>').append($('<img>').attr('src', info.buffer)));
            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
          }
        });

        socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
          $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
          window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        });

        var uploadFile = function() {
          var file = $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0];
          $('input[type=file]').val('')
          if (file) {
              var reader = new FileReader();
              reader.readAsDataURL(file);
              reader.onload = function (event) {
                  socket.emit('image', { image: true, buffer: event.target.result });
              }
              reader.onerror = function (event) {
                  console.log('Error reading file: ', event);
              }
          }
        }
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Server:

```
var app = require('express')();
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
  socket.on('image', function(msg){
    socket.emit('image', msg);
  });
});

http.listen(port, function(){
  console.log('listening on *:' + port);
});
```

Comment: Yes i have learnt from there itself but the image sending which i'm talking about is not mentioned there.Also i have image which are displayed on client side once clicked on button but it is not sent to other clients in the broadcast and also it is not emmiting the image properly to the server don't know why.

Comment: Ok so with the image aside you can successfully emit an event and successfully receive it? That would be step one, once you've confirmed that's working then it's a matter of making sure that data is being sent so try something simple like a short string. Once you've verified that send and receiving works then it's a matter of getting the proper image data. When the client sends the image data how is that being generated? You would probably want a base64 image string

Comment: If the images are pre generated and you're simply requesting the file from the server then sending the image url would work. If you are generating the images on the fly on the client then you would need to get the raw base64 image string and send that in the event

Comment: Yes with strings,text, it works fine but it doesn't work with image. See, what i did is, first i converted the selected image file into base64 image string then i appended that image to that particular chatbox from where i have selected image and its also visible in that chatbox.

Comment: Then emitted it but whats happening is that its giving me output as null like when i emit it from my client.js file to server.js file and when i console log the value(base64 image string) catched by the server.js file, its giving output as null, don't know why, because its displaying image using raw data for that client who selects image but then it should also work for others, which is not happening.

Comment: I have posted the codes, please do take a look at it and let me know what you have to say :)

Comment: I tried the above code that you sent. Its working fine with text but not with images.It's not displaying any image once chosen, neither on client side , nor server is catching the buffer part

Comment: what i noticed is if we write socket.emit(image) under reader,load section then its not emitting the information. but if we use it outside of it then its emitting information but somehow i dont know why its unable to catch the event.target.result outside the 'if'  and i tried making use of global variable and the stored the event.target.result in that variable suppose var data, and then when i put that data out of if statement into socket.emit(image:true, buffer:data) then after emitting i checked if server is able to catch  that buffer:data but its displaying 'undefined' for data(variable)

Comment: and so i also checked the 'data' value in client.js by console.log data in if(file)..eg:if(file){read.load(function(){//code});socket.emit('image', //code}console.log(data)//this data gave me value as undefined in terminal);}

Comment: the var data which i mentioned above is a global variable

Comment: Weird when i test everything works fine. Like I mentioned in the edit 2 larger images have a hard time and dont seem to send

Comment: Thanks very much mate .now its working :) but Now its working with images of small size in kb's ..its not working for images of larger size..Yeah man large image files are not working...Any solution?

Comment: Impose a file size limit or rework how images are sent. You could probably upload directly to the server via an http post, store them on the server and send out a socket event with the url. While it doesnt sound like there are size limits on socket event payloads theres probably a set timeout on how long events take to send